# Send data from Java Socket Server to Python client

Tags: java, python, sockets

I am trying to transmit data too and from a Java server and a Python client. I am successfully able to transmit data from the client to server, but no data is received at all.

On the python client, I have this: (Note that this is ran within a separate Thread)

```
#mp_log is a custom function for logging, treat it as a print.
def listen_loop():
global client_socket

mp_log("Client socket value:")
mp_log(repr(client_socket))

while True:
    mp_log("Waiting on data from the server. Inside while.")

    if client_socket is None:
        mp_log("Client Socket is null, skipping data check.")
        continue
    data = client_socket.recv(1)
    mp_log("Got some data: " + data)
```

If this was to work successfully, the output would be client socket value, waiting on server, then got some data. However, it is getting stuck at waiting on data.

This means that the socket clearly isn't None, and it's waiting on the buffer to be received? I set the receive buffer size to 1 to see if any data at all came through. Here is my send code from the server:

```
// Earlier in the code, to create the writer. 
this.writer = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(),true);
```

I have autoflush enabled as testing to be sure the data is actually being flushed.

```
public void send(String data) {
    System.out.println("Sending data to this client.");

    this.writer.println(data);
    this.writer.flush();
}
```

I know this method is being called due to the console output appearing.

What I find odd is that I am able to send data from the python client, but specifically not receive anything.
Other things I have tried, and have failed, is using other methods of output such as DataOutputStream.

EDIT: Adding the socket creation code for both languages used.
Java:

```
public Connection(Socket socket) throws IOException {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.socket.getInputStream()));

    this.writer = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(),true);

    this.listenThread = new Thread(this);
    this.listenThread.start();

    // Test message
    send("Test Message " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

And Python:

```
global client_socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
threading.Thread(target=listen_loop).start()
client_socket.connect(("localhost", 5000))
```

Comment: 'waiting on data' happens before client_socket is None check, so how do you determine that client_socket is not None ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet because the "Client socket is null" message is not printed.

Comment: My bad. Did not read the code correctly. What's the output of print( client_socket.recv(1) ) ?

Comment: @RambarunKomaljeet that's the point - there is no output. recv waits until data is recieved, and then nothing is printed. I know the data isn't a blank space or \n due to the fact that within the logs it shows everything inside two quotes to check for that. It would seem this function (the mp_log) isn't even called. "Got some data" does not even appear proving this.

Comment: sorry, this is beyond my skill set :x.

Comment: `client_socket.recv(1)` waits for data and `mp_log("Got some data: " + data)` never gets called, so either your `client_socket` is `None` (causing the `while`-loop to just spin) or the call to `recv` never returns, meaning no data is coming in.

Comment: @Poohl It can't be none due to none of the logs about it actually being none (as seen in the code). I am assuming no data is coming in, but then it's working out **why**. Note the Java code, it seems that everything should be there to transmit it

Comment: Ok, data being sent but not received usually shouldn't happen if you can establish the connection, since a runnung TCP connection requires exactly that to happen on a regular basis. And I can't see any issue with the Java code provided (I'm not an expert on python), maybe providing the lines where the sockets are created might help. In general the issue might be caused by the data not beeing send from/to the os or some kind of network-problem.

Comment: @Poohl yeah, that's what's odd. I will update the question to include the socket creation code used.

Answer (score 0):

```
 `data = client_socket.recv(1)`
```

Try to change that by `data=client_socket.recv(1024)`
I think i'm not sure i had a similar issue like that the number you are given to recv(1) is your buffer, wish can help

Comment: I have just tested this, and it didn't work. I would believe that if the given buffer size is smaller than the one that the server is transmitting, it would just split it into lots of buffers.